# Scanf in Assembly ARM for a string

Tags: assembly, arm, scanf

I'm trying to get a user input which should be a 7 character string: like Asd1Fd4.

is there a way to pass the string to an array?

this is what I'm trying to do:

```
.cpu cortex-a72
.fpu neon-fp-armv8

.data
getinp: .string "%s"

.text
.align 2
.global getUserInput
.type getUserInput, %function

getUserInput:
    push {fp, lr} @ store fp and lr on the stack
    add fp, sp, #4 @ using fp to mark th location of LR

    @ scanf("%s", sp)
    mov r1, r0
    ldr r0, =getinp
    bl scanf

     
    @restoring fp and Lr
    sub sp, fp, #4
    pop {fp, pc}
```

the r0 contains the address of my Array

```
sub sp, sp, #28
mov r0, sp
bl getUserInput
```

But this does not work. The `scanf` passes the characters to the r1, r2, r3, .. registers I guess.

Comment: Usage `int myInt; scanf("%d", &myInt);`. What makes you believe that "passes the characters to the r1, r2, r3" ? Disclaimer: your guess is wrong

Comment: And BTW, there are abundance of examples on StackOverflow about calling/using `scanf` from assembly

Comment: Why are you doing this? Isn't user input in C hard enough?

Comment: `mov r0, r1` - scanf returns in `r0` which you're overwriting with whatever garbage it left in `r1`.  It returns a count of the number of successful conversions.  Maybe look at (optimized) C compiler output for code that calls scanf, and think about how each instruction implements part of the C logic. (And check the docs for the calling convention).  Because your current guesswork seems to be totally wrong, except for the `ldr r0, =getinp` which is right.  (Except the comment says `%s` but the string data at that label is `%d`)

Comment: @PeterCordes you were right it is passing the string to the array. Thanks!